# Sum Values of Object in a Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

trying to sum my values from my Object in my Array

I have 3 Objects and in every Object there are two fields where i have values declared:

```
let items = [
       {
        id: 1, 
        label: 'test', 
        itemname: 'testitem', 
        pieces: 4,
        weight: 0.02
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        label: 'test', 
        itemname: 'testitem', 
        pieces: 4,
        weight: 0.02
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        label: 'test', 
        itemname: 'testitem', 
        pieces: 4,
        weight: 0.02
      }
    ];
```

so if i am right the weight sum would be 0.06 and the sum of the pieces would be 12, both multiplied that would be 0.72, that means i want to multiply the sum of the weight with the sum of the pieces.

i saw examples like this:

```
const weight = items.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  return prev + (cur.weight * cur.pieces);
}, 0);
console.log(weight);
```

with this example the total sum would be only 0.24.
Could someone help me here out

Edit: @Robby Cornelissen was right with his comment. It was a wrong way of thinking on my part.

Comment: *"[...] so if i am right the weight sum would be 0.06 and the sum of the pieces would be 12 both multiplied that would be 0.72 [...]"* You are not right. The code gives the correct result. `(a * b) + (c * d) != (a + c) * (b + d)` But that doesn't seem to bother those answering this question to provide you with code that will arrive at your incorrect result.

Comment: Its because  this happening `4*0.02 + 4*0.02 + 4*0.02` not this `(4+4+4)*(0.02+0.02+0.02)`

Comment: Why do you want to multiply the two sums? That's not how you get the total weight.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen my fault you're right in this case it should be 0.24 because it has first to sum the first item with the pieces or better quantity and then the next item  and next thank you i thinkg i should not stay the whole night up anymore haha

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total(sum) weight of all items, you will have to get the weight of each individual item first then add them all together.

```
const sum = (arr) => {
    return arr.map(item => item.pieces * item.weight).reduce((current, total) => current + total)
}
```

```js
let items = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'test',
    itemname: 'testitem',
    pieces: 4,
    weight: 0.02
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'test',
    itemname: 'testitem',
    pieces: 4,
    weight: 0.02
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'test',
    itemname: 'testitem',
    pieces: 4,
    weight: 0.02
  }
]

const sum = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(item => item.pieces * item.weight).reduce((current, total) => current + total)
}

const totalWeight = sum(items)

console.log(totalWeight)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forEach` to loop through the array, adding up the `pieces` and `weight` values:

```
let pieces = 0; // sum of pieces
let weight = 0; // sum of weight
items.forEach(function(elmt){
    pieces += elmt.pieces;
    weight += elmt.weight;
});
```

Then multiply `pieces` * `weight`:

```
let total = pieces * weight;
console.log(total);
```

Comment: What's the point of showing how to get the wrong answer? It makes no sense to multiply these sums.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? OP wrote _"I want to multiply the sum of the weight with the sum of the pieces"_ and that's exactly what my code does.

Comment: First he wrote "If I am right". The problem is that he misunderstood the basic math of what he's trying to do.

Comment: What would be the application of multiplying the sum of weights with the sum of pieces? How could that be the right calculation for anything meaningful? He's updated the question to admit that he misunderstood.

Comment: OP wrote _"so if I am right the weight sum would be 0.06 and the sum of the pieces would be 12"_. OP is right: the weight sum is 0.06 and the sum of the pieces is 72. I answered the question as asked. *After* I wrote my answer, OP update the question to change their requirements. I don't think it's my fault that OP changed their mind after I answered their question as it was asked. I'm happy to delete my answer if it no longer answers the edited question, but I don't think it's right to criticize my answer for no longer applying.

Answer (score -1):

Using `class`

```js
let items=[{id:1,label:"test",itemname:"testitem",pieces:4,weight:.02},{id:2,label:"test",itemname:"testitem",pieces:4,weight:.02},{id:2,label:"test",itemname:"testitem",pieces:4,weight:.02}];

class total {
  weight = 0;
  pieces = 0;
  get product() {
    return this.weight * this.pieces;
  }
}

const totalObj = items.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev.weight += cur.weight;
  prev.pieces += cur.pieces;
  return prev;
}, new total);

console.log(totalObj.product);
```

Comment: If all of you could stop providing answers that arrive at the wrong result, that would be great.